# format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program that will show elements from the int array. But I keep getting the warning. This is probably going to get really downvoted but I don't know where I made a mistake.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
     int counter;
     int elements[3] = { 22, 52, 95 };

     for (counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
         printf("Element %d: %d\n", counter, elements);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: arrays start at 0, and you forgot to use array access syntax inside the loop

Comment: `printf("Element %d: %d\n", counter, elements);` --> `printf("Element %d: %d\n", counter, elements[counter-1]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to print an `int` but `elements` is not an `int`;

**it is an array**!

- You want to use `[]` to retrieve one `int` at a time
- Array in `C` are `0`-indexed. So it means that you should access them starting from the `0`th element.

Check the following:

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
     printf("Element %d: %d\n", counter, elements[counter]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
for(counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++)
{
    printf("Element %d: %d\n", counter, elements[counter]);
}
```

Edit:
Clarification: Loop should run from 0 as "C" arrays are 0 based, the max size if up to "n-1" where n is array size. Next %d will need the element not the array itself. To access the array element, you'll need to use the "[]" operator.

Answer (score 0):

here is your corrected code, with embedded comments about each change

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf()
// only include headers those contents are actually used
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <ctype.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
//#include <time.h>

int main( void ) // only two valid signatures for 'main()'
                 // 'int main( void )' and
                 // 'int main( int argc, char *argv[] )'
{
     size_t counter;  // sizeof() returns a 'size_t' not an 'int'
     int elements[] = { 22, 52, 95 }; // compiler can make the count

     // indexes start at 0 and end at number of elements -1
     // don't hard code 'magic' numbers.  In this case let the compiler do the work
     for (counter = 0; counter < sizeof(elements)/sizeof(int); counter++)
     {
         // remember to index the array
         // remember that an array name, by itself,
         // degrades to the first address of the array
         // the 'counter' is now a 'size_t' so the format specifier must match
         printf("Element %lu: %d\n", counter, elements[ counter ]);
     }

     return 0;
}
```